# MySQL query for nested or join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, nested, left-join

I have such a MYSQL table

```
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `screen_name` text NOT NULL,
  `user_no` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I need to create an SQL query.

- ORDER BY `id` DESC
- GROUP BY `screen_name`
- Get "name" and "screen_name" fields
- `id` between $idmin and $idmax

I will compare the performance of **nested query** and **JOIN query** seperately.
Can you propose query words?
Thank you

Edit: For nested query I tried this:

```
SELECT `name`,`screen_name` FROM `mytable` WHERE `id` IN
(SELECT `id` FROM `mytable` WHERE `id` BETWEEN 100 AND 500 ORDER BY `id` DESC)
GROUP BY `screen_name`
```

I couldn't write for joined type.

Edit2: Say it I have such rows:

- id=1, screen_name=mike, name=uk
- id=2, screen_name=albert, name=usa
- id=3, screen_name=ash, name=uk
- id=4, screen_name=albert, name=new_zelland

I need to get results like this:
id=4
id=3
id=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be in this format:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id, user_no, screen_name
FROM table_name
WHERE id BETWEEN $idmin AND $idmax
GROUP BY screen_name
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC;
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5945e/3)

or with sub-query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.screen_name
FROM example a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT screen_name, MAX(id) id
                FROM example
                WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 4
                GROUP BY screen_name
               ) b
        ON a.screen_name = b.screen_name
           AND a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.id DESC;
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5945e/14)

Comment: Well, that doesn't order by ID. Without nested or join query, when mysql finds first screen_name it doesn't gather any more that type of screen_name which has newer id.

Comment: I tried similar solution to this. But couldn't make it http://www.cafewebmaster.com/mysql-order-sort-group

Comment: Doesn't MAX(id) gives one record? I need all records matching this criteria? Am I wrong?

Comment: you must choose one id as you are using `GROUP BY screen_name`.

Comment: Well, I need to take all scrren_names in one query that are grouped by each screen_name..

Comment: then ideally you should be doing `ORDER BY screen_name DESC;`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15888/discussion-between-omesh-and-trante)

Comment: Sorry but one thing is not clear for me. From the example of "edit2" of my question. Your first code snippet gives ids of 1,3 and 4. But data of id=4 is id=2. I mean the result includes this: "max id:4, id:2, name=usa". But I need name="new zelland".

Comment: ya second query will give you the exact data 4 with 'new zelland'. first query won't work for you. check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5945e/14

Comment: Second query worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your effort, you really saved my day :))